# Using Excel Formula in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Currently I have the following formula working perfectly when entered directly into the excel sheet. 
   `=AVERAGEIFS(A:A,A:A,">="&10,A:A,"<="&11)`

However, when I attempt to exectue it in VBA it says there is a formatting error.

`Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.AverageIfs(A:A,A:A,">="&10,A:A,"<="&11)`

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use **Range()** to define ranges in VBA:

```
Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.AverageIfs(Range("A:A"), Range("A:A"), ">=10", Range("A:A"), ">=11")
```